# How pass json value for admin-update-user-attributes operation via cli in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Consider the example:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes --user-pool-id myUserPollId
--username myUser 
--user-attributes [{"Name": "custom:roles","Value": "ROLE1,ROLE2"}] --region us-east-1
```

This gets me error:

```
Invalid JSON:
    [{Name:
```

Answer (score 5):

1. You can always try using shorthand syntax:

   ```
   --user-attributes Name="custom:roles",Value="ROLE1,ROLE2"
   ```
2. If you really want to use the JSON syntax, try this:

   ```
   --user-attributes '[{"Name" : "custom:roles","Value" : "ROLE1,ROLE2"}]'
   ```

   - Ensure that the user-attributes list is enclosed in single quotes

Answer (score 1):

```
--user-attributes '[{"Name": "phone_number", "Value": "+123434532"}, 
{"Name": "name", "Value":"name_your"}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone get stuck in the same problem again, below are the tested steps to have *user attributes* updated via *aws cli with json* file.

**Step 0:** Setup *AWS CLI* in case you haven't already. Mac users can run:

```
brew install awscli
```

**Step 1:** Have a valid json handy with you, saved in a file. Sample json with valid format:

```
{
  "UserAttributes": [{
      "Name": "custom:additional-attribute1",
      "Value": "Value for additional attribute 1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "custom:additional-attribute2",
      "Value": "Value for additional attribute 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Step 2:** Run the following in your console:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes --user-pool-id XX-XXXX-X_XXXXXXXXX --username XXXXX@XXXXX.com --cli-input-json file:///Users/YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_FILE/user-attributes.json
```

Parameters:

```
--user-pool-id :: Your user pool ID.
--username :: The user you want to udpate.
--cli-input-json :: This is the command that loads json file and parses it.
```

That's it. If your json is valid and aws cli authorises, the given user record should be updated instantly.