# Using bash variable as argument in AWS CLI command

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I have a JSON string which I want to store in a custom attribute of a user in AWS cognito.

```
DATA="[{\"attr1\":\"value1\",\"attr2\":\"value2\"},{\"attr1\":\"value3\",\"attr2\":\"value4\"}]"
```

I tried the following but none is working:

```
aws cognito-idp --region $REGION admin-update-user-attributes 
--user-pool-id $USERPOOL_ID --username $USERNAME --user-attributes '[{"Name":"custom:data","Value":"$DATA"}]'

aws cognito-idp --region $REGION admin-update-user-attributes 
--user-pool-id $USERPOOL_ID --username $USERNAME --user-attributes '[{"Name":"custom:data","Value":"${DATA}"}]'

aws cognito-idp --region $REGION admin-update-user-attributes 
--user-pool-id $USERPOOL_ID --username $USERNAME --user-attributes '[{"Name":"custom:data","Value":"'${DATA}'"}]'

r1='[{"Name":"custom:data","Value":"'
r2='"}]'
r3=$r1$DATA$r2
aws cognito-idp --region $REGION admin-update-user-attributes 
--user-pool-id $USERPOOL_ID --username $USERNAME--user-attributes $r3

aws cognito-idp --region $REGION admin-update-user-attributes 
--user-pool-id $USERPOOL_ID --username $USERNAME--user-attributes "${r3}"

aws cognito-idp --region $REGION admin-update-user-attributes 
--user-pool-id $USERPOOL_ID --username $USERNAME--user-attributes << EOF [{"Name":"custom:data","Value":"$DATA"}] 
EOF
```

What's the correct way to do it? The JSON string is actually not a static text so it cannot be hard-coded in the command.

Comment: In your first attempt, put a backslash before every double-quote, and then change the single quotes to double-quotes.

Comment: Thanks! It works with a static string currently. But not with the string that I got from the AWS cognito custom attribute using jq. It might be due to the lack of escape characters in the string? Any way to fix that?

Comment: in aws documentation the value of --user-attributes is not in quotes `--user-attributes Name="custom:data",Value="YourString"` [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-update-user-attributes.html]. I am not sure if DATA should be a string in your case since it's an array of JSON. But you can try not quoting Name and Value, as it is in the link I sent

Comment: There is a similar question with answers here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429352/how-pass-json-value-for-admin-update-user-attributes-operation-via-cli-in-aws]